# Враг, отвергать

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова "**вр**аг" и "отвергать" к этимологически однокоренным, исходя из:

1. Наличие в старославянском чередования согласных а->е

Например:

стр**а**жить (сторожить) -> стр**е**щи (стеречь);
вл**а**чить (волочить) -> вл**е**щи (влечь)

2. Соответствие русского глагола отвергать старославянскому от**вр**ещи

Answer (score 2):

Согласно Словарю русского языка XVIII века (Л.: Наука, 1984) "отврещи" пребывает в родстве с "вергу". Отсюда связь и с "отвергаю".

О связи с "враг", к сожалению, ничего сказать не могу.